# Optaplanner - Error when running executable jar but works fine from eclipse

Tags: java, drools, executable-jar, optaplanner, reflections

I use eclipse for my optaplanner project development and I am able to execute my code from eclipse without any problem. To make this project as an executable, I exported it as a jar file using eclipse export wizard.

Then I run my jar from terminal using the command `java -jar myOptaPlanner.jar`, then, I get below error

```
WARN  given scan urls are empty. set urls in the configuration
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The scanAnnotatedClasses 
(ScanAnnotatedClassesConfig()) did not find any classes with a PlanningSolution 
annotation.
Maybe you forgot to annotate a class with a PlanningSolution annotation.
Maybe you're using special classloading mechanisms (OSGi, ...) and this is a bug. 
If you can confirm that, report it to our issue tracker and workaround it by 
defining the classes explicitly in the solver configuration.
at org.optaplanner.core.config.domain.ScanAnnotatedClassesConfig.loadSolutionClass(ScanAnnotatedClassesConfig.java:106)
at org.optaplanner.core.config.domain.ScanAnnotatedClassesConfig.buildSolutionDescriptor(ScanAnnotatedClassesConfig.java:86)
at org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig.buildSolutionDescriptor(SolverConfig.java:270)
at org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig.buildSolver(SolverConfig.java:216)
at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolverFactory.buildSolver(AbstractSolverFactory.java:57)
at org.roster.app.WorkerRosteringApp.main(WorkerRosteringApp.java:36)
```

Is this really a bug or am I exporting it wrong?

Update: I tried to export jar using `maven-shade-plugin` and here also I am getting the same error.

Thanks

Comment: Under the covers, OptaPlanner uses org.reflections to scan the classpath. I 've tested this with jars without any trouble. Are you using OSGi, Jigsaw, JBoss Modules or any other special classloading environments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

scanAnnotatedClasses doesn't seem to work in a jar file. Instead, use following workaround:

```
<solutionClass>path.to.your.SolutionClass</solutionClass>
<entityClass>path.to.your.EntityClassI</entityClass>
<entityClass>path.to.your.EntityClassII</entityClass>
```

and delete the `scanAnnotatedClasses` in your config file.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help... It is working now. Do you think I have to post this to them as a bug?

Comment: Yes, this is a bug, please [report it here](https://issues.jboss.org/projects/PLANNER) and provide a clean reproducer

Comment: Or better yet, figure out what the problem is [by debugging this code](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-core/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/core/config/domain/ScanAnnotatedClassesConfig.java#L86), if you want to contribute.

Comment: got similar issue on one of my tomcat with OptaPlanner 7.48.0 and it "solved" this

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to declare the solution and entity classes manually, including the packages containing the solution and entity classes also works as workaround:

```
<scanAnnotatedClasses>
    <packageInclude>your.package.here</packageInclude>
</scanAnnotatedClasses>
```

Documentation about `<packageInclude>` can be found [here](https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.0.0.Beta5/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#annotationsConfiguration)